# How to inline only the CSS that a page uses instead of loading the whole framework?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize, amp-html

I have a page that uses Materialize CSS. It uses almost nothing from the framework other than a container, the basic font styling and the following:

```
<div id="benefits">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l6">
      <h2>Neat colors</h2>
      <div>...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything I can do with Sass (unfamiar with it) or Webpack (semi familiar with it) or anything else that would allow me to extract only the CSS that the page uses and inline it? If I was good at CSS I probably would hand-roll it but that is not the case.

Ultimately, I'd like to make the page AMP compliant—maybe there is a better way to achieve this altogether...

Comment: "I'd like to make the page AMP compliant" - but AMP is dead...

Comment: @Dai like dead, dead? Why do you say that? I want receipts :p

Comment: https://plausible.io/blog/google-amp  https://om.co/2021/05/19/ding-dong-google-amp-is-dead/ https://www.reddit.com/r/Frontend/comments/nh0kbn/google_amp_is_dead_amp_pages_no_longer_get/ https://technoogies.com/google-amp-is-dead-pretty-sure/

Answer (score 1):

Atomized CSS is a good technique for inlining CSS.

If you're looking to use only what you absolutely need, this is worth checking out.

> ACSS relies on Atomizer to dynamically generate an Atomic stylesheet
> from the ACSS classes you're actually using in your project (no unused
> styles!), or predeclare styles in configuration - it's up to you. ACSS
> is not opinionated, brings no CSS of its own, and integrates nicely
> with your favorite task runner.

[Atomic CSS](https://acss.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [purgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/plugins/webpack.html). It is a webpack plugin that purges css based on html files